# My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText doesn't rise any exception when the file is open

Tags: .net, vb.net, file

I'm using the "My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText" (vb .net) to add lines to an existing text file, everything works fine but I'm concerned about one thing: If I have already opened the file (via windows explorer) the "My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText" doesn't rise any exception, in fact it does append the information to the file. I mean, if I do the following:

Open the file via windows explorer >>> Execute "My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText" >>> Close the file without saving anything >>> Open again the file via windows explorer

I can see the text appended! Is this "normal"? I would expect getting any kind of error because of writing permissions. If there is no control when opening the file, how does the code manage if two different processes try to write to the files at the same time?

I've done another test:

Open the file via windows explorer >>> Modify the text >>> Execute "My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText" >>> Close the file saving changes >>> Open again the file via windows explorer

Then the text added by "My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText" disappears, I only see the text I've added manually, what seems logical to me as I've saved it after executing the code, what I don't understand is why I don't get any error with the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _Open the file via windows explorer_ really Windows Explorer launch an application that reads the file (depending on the extension). Now, if the application opens the file just for read, loads it in its memory and then closes the file or just don't ask for exclusive access then you are able to write in that file

Comment: When I open the file via windows explorer (let's say that I open it with the Notepad for example), I open it for writing, or at least I cad edit the file, change the content and then save and close. The "My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText" also opens the file for writing, so why there is no conflict between then? Or let's say it different, how can I be sure that two different processes aren't modifying the same file at the same time?

Comment: There are [many ways to open a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=net-5.0). Some of them let you specify a lot of conditions about sharing the file with other applications or keep it exclusive. It depends on how Notepad opens the file.

Comment: OK, I've dug deeper and done some tests and now I understand how everything works: when you open a file with windows Notepad, it doesn't actually locks the file, so other processes can edit the file while it's open (really, really dangerous!). This is the same that happens if you open the file with WordPad for instance. However, if you open the same file with Microsoft Word or Excel, this two programs do lock the files while they are open and then the "My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText" finally rises an error.